# no sound in ubuntu 14.04 and wifi problem

Tags: 14.04

[image: sound settings snapshot]

I am on ubuntu 14.04 and I have tried installing and uninstalling my drivers but nothing seems to work.

No sound at all. Sound settings dashboard shows nothing to select for sound output. Also, no wifi drivers.

How could I get both of these to work properly?